# SCJP or SCJP plus?

Tags: java, oracle, scjp

The previous questions on SO that I came across are nearly 2 years old.

I have just purchased Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates book for SCJP 6. But it happens so that now on my reading the blogs, I hear of SCJP "PLUS" exam that is supposed to overshadow and possibly retire the SCJP exam!

I searched for hours on net about the exam but all threads are very old.

So can anyone provide me with an updated information about this exam; whether it has already hit the test centers? or still SCJP is alive? Or if SCJP is still alive, is it worth to take that?

**EDIT For future references:** 
Found the Answer:
The Oracle Certified Associate, Java SE 7 Programmer is available as of now but Oracle Certified Professional, Java SE 7 Programmer is still not launched. http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=41&p_org_id=&lang=&p_exam_id=1Z0_804

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Oracle bought Sun. I think you will find more info if you search for:

[OCPJP (Oracle Certified Professional Java SE Programmer)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Certified_Professional).

[Oracle Certification Program](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=140)

I expected that the topics will be very similar to old exams so that you can learn with your book. I used that one too.

Answer (score 2):

As long as it's at least SCJP 5, it shouldn't matter much. The difference between Java 5 and 7 is much smaller IMO than say 4 and 5. Most reasonable employers should just be happy that you have a piece of paper saying you have basic competence with modern Java. That's all SCJP says. You'd need the enterprise ones to go into more depth, but I've never met a prospective employer that cared much about Java certs anyway.

Comment: Ok. I get it. But has SCJP plus been launched?